# OpenCart extension upgrade

Tags: php, opencart

I have custom extension for OpenCart 3.x which works fine. The extension uses custom DB tables to store information.

Now I upgraded the extension to a new version which have one additional table in the DB.

My issue is that I can’t find any info how to tell OpenCart that there is an update and just add this table.

In PrestaShop is quite easy, just add update_VERSION.php which contains all changes for the new version, so is there anything similar to this for OC?

Comment: From your comment on the answer below, it seems you're looking for how to execute upgrade code on installation if there is a previous version of the plugin. Is this correct? Are you the developer looking for help or the user having trouble with a plugin?

Comment: Yea, you are 100% right! I’m am the developer of the extension.

Comment: Are you using install.php for the table creation on installation?

Comment: No, just the install() method to invoke the createTables method from the model class. All DB queries have CREATE IF NOT EXIST statement, so, there is not a big deal if they run multiple times

Comment: Ok, well you can include a file called install.php outside of the 'upload' directory but in the zip. In that file you can use the default Opencart classes / libraries to execute the relevant installation / upgrade code etc. I haven't personally used it but have seen a number of different extensions use this for all sorts of things (including notifying the author on installation). Does this help?

Comment: I tried with the index.php, but this seems to be like a workaround thing... basically I need to search if all missing tables and corrections are fine, if not then correct them, but it will be a nightmare after few minor versions right? Because the upgrade can be in events, extension settings, existing table structure. As I understood so far OC does not reliably supports such feature - to gradually make upgrades between installed version and the new one. Am I right?

Comment: Great, so you should have a way forward now. I can't comment on how tricky the upgrade path will be as this is correlated to the number of features and the frequency of breaking changes. It should be manageable though. I'm not sure what you mean by "OC does not reliably support such a feature" though, perhaps you should look at their forums and discuss there?

Answer (score 0):

If properly written extension, it should update also properly, does not matter OC or prestashop. So if you need to install just only additional DB table you can do it in phpmyadmin. Another way, you can copy that table code to you admin controller somewhere after `public function index() {`  and when you open that module in OC admin, table should install.

That query should look something like this:

```
$this->db->query("
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "your_additinal_table` (
                `some_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `bla_bla` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                `another_bla_bla` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY `some_id` (`some_id`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
        ");
```

After that you can delete that code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This does not make any sense really.. the issue is that I don’t see a way as a developer to provide a way to gradually update the module version without the need my customers to reinstall it!

Comment: Your question was ho to install. You got an answer. If you are developer you easily can do it by yourself using my suggestions. You can, place code which will check if the some version is installed, place button to upgrade in admin module settings... And under this button organize DB table installation. Or just leave DB query code for table installation in admin controller file forever. This code will check if DB table not exists just install it thats all. Of course my code just an example. You must use your own.